# XMLHTTPRequest send data

Tags: javascript, php, json, wordpress, rest

I want to add post in the database with WordPress. I tried this code.

wordpress\wp-content\themes\twentyseventeen\index.php:

```html
<div class="admin-quick-add">
    <h3>Quick Add post</h3>
    <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title">
    <textarea name="content" placeholder="Content"></textarea>
    <button id="quick-add-button">Create Post</button>
   </div>
```

wordpress\wp-content\themes\twentyseventeen\assets\js:

```js
quickAddButton = document.querySelector("#quick-add-button");

if (quickAddButton) {
 quickAddButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var OurPOSTData = {
   "title": document.querySelector('.admin-quick-add [name="title"]').value,
   "content": document.querySelector('.admin-quick-add [name="content"]').value,
   "status": "publish",
  }
  
  //alert (JSON.stringify(OurPOSTData));
  
  var createPost = new XMLHttpRequest();
  createPost.open('POST', 'http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/posts');
  createPost.setRequestHeader("X-WP-Nonce", magicalData.nonce);
  createPost.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
  createPost.send(JSON.stringify(OurPOSTData));
 });
}
```

wordpress\wp-content\themes\twentyseventeen\functions.php

```
function twentyseventeen_scripts() {
/* Some code */

// My Script
wp_enqueue_script( 'main_js',  get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/js/main.js' ), NULL, 1.0, true);  /* Some code */ } add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'twentyseventeen_scripts' );
```

but it does not work.

Comment: where is your functions.php code?

Comment: Do you want all the code of the file?

Comment: im getting this error. `{"code":"rest_cannot_create","message":"Sorry, you are not allowed to create posts as this user.","data":{"status":401}}` where is username and password in header?

Comment: How can I add them please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

*add your username and password*

```
quickAddButton = document.querySelector("#quick-add-button");

if (quickAddButton) {
quickAddButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var OurPOSTData = {
        "title": document.querySelector('.admin-quick-add [name="title"]').value,
        "content": document.querySelector('.admin-quick-add [name="content"]').value,
        "status": "publish",
    }

    //alert (JSON.stringify(OurPOSTData));

    var createPost = new XMLHttpRequest();
    createPost.open('POST', 'http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/posts');
    createPost.setRequestHeader("X-WP-Nonce", magicalData.nonce);
    createPost.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    createPost.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + window.btoa("username:password"));
    createPost.send(JSON.stringify(OurPOSTData));
});
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to tell you that I added this code in functions.php `wp_localize_script( 'main_js', 'magicalData', array(
  'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('wp_rest')
 ));` after `wp_enqueue_script( 'main_js',  get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/js/main.js' ), NULL, 1.0, true);` I corrected that in the question

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: Base64 is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous>

Comment: Please check how to convert base64 in JavaScript

Comment: I used `window.btoa("username:password")` instead of `Base64.encode( 'username:password' ))` but it doesn't work and there are no console errors.

Comment: You have to change username value and password value. Did you check as need that?

Comment: Yes I did that.

Comment: it works with `window.btoa("username:password")` instead of `Base64.encode( 'username:password' ))`